# Creating a complex sequence in R which skips iterations number without using a loop

Tags: r, vector, sequence, rep

The following sequence:

```
1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
```

can be generated with a loop

```
x <- c(); for (i in 1:3) x <- c(x, 1:3)
```

or (preferably) without a loop

```
x <- rep(1:3, 3)
```

Now, I want to remove `i` from the sequence in the i-th iteration, to get:

```
2 3 1 3 1 2
```

It is easy to achieve this by modifying the loop, but how to do this without a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an idea:

```r
x <- rep(1:3, 3)
x[x != rep(1:3, each = 3)]

# [1] 2 3 1 3 1 2
```

Another presentation:

```r
matrix(1:3, 3, 3)[!diag(TRUE, 3)]

# [1] 2 3 1 3 1 2
```

Answer (score 3):

A fast solution using `sequence`:

```
n <- 3L
sequence(rep(n, n - 1L), 1:n) %% n + 1L
#> [1] 2 3 1 3 1 2
```

Benchmark (based on Zheyuan Li's):

```
f1 <- function (n) rep.int(1:n, n)[-seq.int(1, n * n, n + 1)]
f2 <- function (n) {
  z <- 1:n
  x <- rep.int(z, n)
  x[x != rep(z, each = n)]
}
f3 <- function(n) sequence(rep(n, n - 1L), 1:n) %% n + 1L
n <- 1000L
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(Li = f1(n),
                               Tsai = f2(n),
                               Blood = f3(n),
                               check = "equal")
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>   expr     min      lq      mean   median      uq     max neval
#>     Li  6.5381  6.7037  8.545134  8.53075  9.0220 32.4803   100
#>   Tsai 11.7392 12.0008 14.599620 14.00125 14.4217 43.2622   100
#>  Blood  3.0204  3.0617  3.514819  3.09375  3.2193  7.8742   100
```

Comment: This is so good to know. I know `sequence` but after staring at it for minutes, I still don't fully understand the math behind it. Good! On my machine, the median times are 16.46, 62.81 and 11.01, respectively.

Comment: I was somewhat surprised by the speed increase. I suspect it is mainly from memory efficiencies. The mod and addition operations can be done in-place, but the negative sunsetting requires new memory allocation.

Answer (score 2):

I thought about this before. I did:

```
n <- 3
x <- rep(1:n, n)[-seq.int(1, n * n, by = n + 1)]
#[1] 2 3 1 3 1 2
```

Nothing will be faster than this for big `n` (of course, unless we code the entire loop in C/C++).

---

**interpretation**

It is as same as dropping diagonal elements from the following matrix:

```
matrix(rep(1:n, n), n)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    1    1
#[2,]    2    2    2
#[3,]    3    3    3
```

which is

```
matrix(x, ncol = n)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    2    1    1
#[2,]    3    3    2
```

This essentially gives the index for training data in a leave-one-out cross-validation.

---

**benchmark**

```
f1 <- function (n) rep.int(1:n, n)[-seq.int(1, n * n, n + 1)]

## Darren Tsai's method
## the logic is also dropping diagonal elements from a matrix
## try mat[row(mat) != col(mat)] for a square matrix `mat`
## but this takes more memory
f2 <- function (n) {
  z <- 1:n
  x <- rep.int(z, n)
  x[x != rep(z, each = n)]
}

n <- 1000
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark("Li" = f1(n), "Tsai" = f2(n))
#Unit: milliseconds
# expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max
#   Li 15.14039 15.18756 19.06687 16.78678 20.44281  52.86618 
# Tsai 61.45718 62.56886 66.01448 62.86677 65.42081 107.46628
```

Comment: I like this method: `mat[row(mat) != col(mat)]`. Another presentation should be `f3 <- function(n) matrix(1:n, n, n)[!diag(TRUE, n)]`. Maybe you could add it to benchmark and I guess it's more efficient than my first answer.

Comment: @DarrenTsai The matrix representation is very intuitive, but takes up more RAM when creating several *n x n* matrices. Your version with `rep` is better. The flexible usage of `rep` in your answer might have better attracted OP. Meanwhile, OP does not care speed anyway... Have a look at jblood94's answer. It is so clever, but also very difficult to understand. :D